# The text inside spans move to bottom after I click an editable span in that row

Tags: html, css

I have a table that contain a few spans in each row, and one of the span is editable.
[image]

After I click on the editable span, all the text in other spans in that row moved to the bottom.(Sorry about phone quality photo, couldn't get screenshot for that one.)

[image]

Is there anyway to prevent them moving down after I click on the editable span?

Comment: Is `vertical-align:top;` already set in the table cells? Please provide some code.

Comment: The table is automatically generated, so the code is kind of messy. And vertical-align:top works, thank you so much! Please write it in answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `vertical-align:top;` in the css for the table cells.